# WebStorm not displaying TypeScript error when passing non existent prop to component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm

I have one WebStorm project where this is working, but another where it isn't - autocomplete is working, but if I try and create a component with a non-existent prop WebStorm doesn't tell me there is a problem.

I've checked the settings of both projects, and the `tsconfig.json` and can't see where the difference lies. What setting could cause this in one project over another?

```js
type Props = {
    text: string
}

const Test = ({text}: Props) => {
    return(
        <div>{text}</div>
    )
}

const Test2 = () => {
  return (
      <Test
          text={'test'}
          anything={'test'} <--- This should display an error
      />
  )
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Run the typescript compiler from the command line to determine if webstorm or your typescript configuration itself is at fault. `./node_modules/.bin/tsc ./tsconfig.json`

Comment: Hmm when I try that I get: File 'tsconfig.json' has an unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.cts', '.d.cts', '.mts', '.d.mts' - looking into that now